# match css rules in javascript

Tags: javascript, css, regex

I need to create a regular expression to find class inside a css file.

For example I have this css file:

```
#label-blu{

}

.label-blu, .test{

}

.label-blu-not-match{

}

.label-blu{

}

.label-blu span{

}
```

In this case I need to return 3 match

This is my regular expression:

```
var css = data;
var find_css = 'label-blu';
var found = css.match(/([#|\.]?)([\w|:|\s|\.]+)/gmi).length;
console.log('found: ' + found);
```

**Inside var data there is all the css string**

How can I solve?

Thanks

Comment: In your example, it doesn't seem you're testing for matches in your css file, rather in your variable 'label-blu'.. if you'd want to test for matches in your file, you could insert that files text into a variable as a trimmed string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two points:

```
("word-does-not-include-hyphen").replace(/\w+/g, 'test')
```

And are you sure you should be matching against css label text `label-blu`? rather than the full css text itself? Currently you are finding the separations across the hyphen for `label-blu`...

```
var css = 'label-blu';
var found = css.match(/([#|\.]?)([\w|:|\s|\.]+)/gmi);
/// which gives ['label','blu']
```

Which is the reason for the returned length of two, rather than three. Were you not hoping to match the three items in the css text i.e

```
#label-blu
.label-blu-not-match
.label-blu
```

If so you will need to use a different text to match, the entire css, rather than just the string 'label-blue'.

However if you are trying to match:

```
#label-blu
.label-blu, .test
.label-blu
.label-blu span
```

Then you will need a different RegExp and the entire css string. Just need clarification on which route you need?

#### update

It's still not clear exactly out of the css text what you wish to match, this is the reason why I have outlined exactly. However, on the assumption you want to match the last four items I mention (and assuming you don't wish to match `label-blu-not-match`) then the following should help:

http://jsfiddle.net/5d7JX/

```
var found = csstext.match(/[#\.]label-blu([,:\s\.][^\{]*)?\{/gmi);
```

However the above is not full-proof for all possible css formats, nor does it protect against matches within the css rule-sets themselves. Generally speaking scanning through code that is usually quite complicated to parse into something logical using only Regular Expressions is frowned upon; unless you are solving a very specific use-case.

#### update 2

Yes excluding the ID selectors just involves removing the `#` part of the Reg Exp...

```
var found = csstext.match(/\.label-blu([,:\s\.][^\{]*)?\{/gmi);
```

I recommend that you read up on your regular expressions, this site is a good place:

http://www.regular-expressions.info/

#### update 3

To include a variable as part of a regular expression you will need to make sure you escape the characters to make the string literal, so any special characters wont interfere. As far as I'm aware there isn't a built in function to escape or quote for regular expressions in JavaScript; however you can find one here:

[How to escape regular expression in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2593637/how-to-escape-regular-expression-in-javascript)

So if you add this to your code:

```
RegExp.quote = function(str) {
  return (str+'').replace(/([.?*+^$[\]\\(){}|-])/g, "\\$1");
};
```

You then also need to convert your regexp to the object equivalent:

```
var reg = new RegExp('\\.label-blu([,:\\s\\.][^\\{]*)?\\{', 'gmi');
var found = csstext.match(reg);
```

And then add this:

```
var label = 'label-blu';
var reg = new RegExp('\\.' + RegExp.quote(label) + '([,:\\s\\.][^\\{]*)?\\{', 'gmi');
var found = csstext.match(reg);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5d7JX/1/

Comment: oh, I need the full string label-blu not separated, yes I'm wrong something I think, but I don't need replace, I need only the number of match inside the css that match with label-blu

Comment: @AlessandroMinoccheri ~ my first part is just an example to show that `\w` does not cover hyphen, you will have be more specific if you wish to include hyphens. The solution to your issue is to switch out `css` for the variable that contains your entire css text.

Comment: ok can you please provide an example? I have update my question

Comment: @AlessandroMinoccheri ~ I've updated my answer, you need to specify exactly what it is you are trying to match from the above full css text.

Comment: I need to get the number of match inside the css with the word label-blu string

Comment: @AlessandroMinoccheri ~ I have updated my answer, but you will most likely need to evolve the RegExp is you wish to use in across more complicated css text.

Comment: but is possible to exclude id to retrieve only class?

Comment: ok now seems to works fine, is possible to insert label-blu like a variable, because is a a variable passed by a function?

Answer (score 0):

In your example if you use:

```
var findClass = /(\.label-blu)(?!-)+/g;
var found = css.match(findClass).length;
```

should return 3...

maybe a better solution is:

```
var findClass = /(\.label-blu)[\s{,]+/g;
var found = css.match(findClass).length;
```

to cover a possibility when you might have something else rather than '-' added to your wanted class and it will only look for the class that's followed by a 'space' a '{' or a ','...

let me know if you have any questions